# Why can the EU be called a project?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From an article in [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/special-report/2022/01/10/however-justified-more-government-intervention-risks-being-counterproductive?utm_medium=social-media.content.np&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=editorial-social&utm_content=discovery.content):

> *Having buried the age of big government under Bill Clinton, Democrats are enthusiastically exhuming it, with even some Republicans cheering
> them on. Britain’s ruling Conservatives have lost their Thatcherite
> moorings. **The EU, a project with a strong interventionist reflex
> from its inception, is giving in to it.***

The European Union (EU) is a political and economic union. The word project has several meanings. But here I can't decide on the right one.

Comment: Have you looked up "project" in a reliable dictionary? Which definitions do you think would fit?

Comment: I thought I found none, whether it refers to"a planned piece of work that is designed to find information about sth, to produce sth new, or to improve sth " or "a set of aims, ideas or activities that sb is interested in or wants to bring to people's attention ".

Comment: @Jones - the legislative and political work required to unify Europe, improve its economy, and make war unlikely (after two big ones in the 20th century) might reasonably be described as 'a planned piece of work that is designed to improve something'.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford (via google) gives "Project: an individual or collaborative enterprise that is carefully planned to achieve a particular aim."  The aim, in this case, is to unite the nations of Europe economically and politically.

Project has connotations of a scheme that continues over a long period of time and into the future. So it is an appropriate word to use.